# Exception handling in TRIGGERS (for each row)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What happens when an exception is raised in a TRIGGER?

Suppose we have a table R(a,b,c,d,e) with the values below:

[image: 5 rows of data in table R]

Now suppose we try to execute `UPDATE R SET b = 2, c = 3 WHERE a = 1` with the trigger listed below in effect:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fd_enforcer_update
BEFORE UPDATE on R
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE counter INT
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter
    FROM R
    WHERE R.A = NEW.A AND R.B = NEW.B AND R.C <> NEW.C
    AND NOT (R.A = OLD.A AND R.B = OLD.B AND R.C = OLD.C AND R.D = OLD.D AND R.E = OLD.E);
    IF (counter > 0 )
    THEN raise_exception();
END;
```

The code above is written to supposedly enforce the functional dependency `AB->C`.

In the example above, the `UPDATE` statement affects four rows. Since we specified `FOR EACH ROW` in the trigger, each of these 4 rows will be checked.

The trigger checks the first of the four rows `[1,1,2,3,4]` and raises an exception. Now, what happens? Does the trigger terminate completely? Or does it go on checking the other three rows?

After my `UPDATE` statement is executed, how many rows are actually updated?

Comment: An exception is raised in the `update`, so the `update` statement terminates and changes are rolled back.  That is what `raise_exception()` does.

Comment: Please post data as formatted test, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Does the update statement only terminate at that specific row? For example, if there's an `UPDATE` statement affects 100 rows... Suppose an exception is only raised when the trigger is checking the 67th row. Will the changes from row 1 to row 66 be rolled back?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This was given as suggested solution to one of my tutorial qns but I wasn't entire convinced. I tried it out in Oracle and was given the error message below. Not sure about the behaviour.

04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Comment: @JTJM . . . The entire *statement* is rolled back.  That is how SQL works, statement by statement, or transaction by transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't understand. Your trigger are written with error. The correct code will be looked like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fd_enforcer_update
BEFORE UPDATE on R
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  counter INT
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO counter
      FROM R
     WHERE R.A = :NEW.A 
       AND R.B = :NEW.B 
       AND R.C <> :NEW.C
    AND NOT (R.A = :OLD.A 
         AND R.B = :OLD.B 
         AND R.C = :OLD.C 
         AND R.D = :OLD.D 
         AND R.E = :OLD.E);
    IF counter > 0 THEN 
      raise_exception();
    END IF; 
END;
```

And if we call `UPDATE R SET b = 2, c = 3 WHERE a = 1`.
Lets assume that update will be begin from top to bottom:
For first row :

```
a | b | c | d | e 
1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

select will be looked like

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO counter
      FROM R
     WHERE R.A = 1
       AND R.B = 2 
       AND R.C <> 3 
    AND NOT (R.A = 1
         AND R.B = 1
         AND R.C = 2
         AND R.D = 3 
         AND R.E = 4)
```

And on current data it return 4 (may be I wriong, but I'm sure it will be more then 0). And trigger called raise_exception() for first row. And whole transaction will be rolled back.